# What would the implications of a landlocked island be?

Tags: alternate-history

For the sake of argument, say that rather than Pangea breaking up, it moved closer together, creating a ring of mountains surrounding some parts of the West Coast of America and the North West area of the African continent.  If this is impossible, then try to ignore that one impossibility for the sake of literary licence.  So we have a large portion of the world rendered inaccessible to the rest of the world until the advent of mountaineering.

Obviously the isolation would have an effect on the evolution of the species that are "trapped" in that area, as we can see with Australia, but that is not the part that I am curious about.  What I am more curious about is the social evolution of hominoid species in that land-locked island.  I am aware that hominoids did not show up until long after the breakup of Pangea, but again for the sake of argument let us say that the precursors to hominoids were also trapped in the ring of mountains.

What are some of the likely social structures an intelligent hominoid species would develop in the tens of thousands of years that they would have been isolated from the world at large?

Comment: Social structures of different species we know nothing about is broad question. There is no particular reason for them to evolve significantly different from us, nor a reason to evolve similarly. Same with social structures, except if they evolved similarly, I would guess that similar to ours make sense.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Also please read the Meta discussion about [How to deal with "I have a high concept, please do my work for me" questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions). What you are asking is extremely broad and opinion-based and can't be answered in a somewhat objective way. That's the case more often than not if someone asks about social structures after introducing a very big change.

Comment: Why isn't Australia the answer? It fits perfectly

Comment: It sounds like you have an idea but need to break it down and either get more information yourself or ask separate questions. For example a reality check on stable pangea, a question on the climate differences of pangea or land area available. Once you've got those ideas you can form your own ideas about social structures - these are always complex and anyone's guess really.

Comment: A quick google gives you a few ideas to start from [climate](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/27ts40/what_was_the_weatherclimate_like_during_pangea/) or [a video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaFdUh6j3aE)

Comment: Thank you all for your in-put.  This is my first time posting on this particular stack exchange so I appreciate your patience as I learn how things are done here.  I shall endeavor to change my question to narrow down what it is I am asking.